# Htaccess rewrite and redirect to url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect to `www.domain.com/store/bg/user/login` whenever someone tries `www.domain.com/STOREADMIN/bg/user/login` ( uppercase is only to emphasize ). The language part of the url can be another language ( `.../../en/../..` ).
This is the whole `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Indexes
# follow symbolic links
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

#RewriteRule ^(store)($|/) - [L]

#RewriteRule ^/store/(.+)  http://store.tashev.bg/$1  [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/storeadmin/[a-z]{2}/user/login
RewriteRule ^/storeadmin/([a-z]{2}) %{HTTP_HOST}/store/$1/user/login [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/$
RewriteRule ^(admin)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
RewriteRule ^admin(/.+)?$ /backend/web/$1 [L,PT]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /frontend/web/$1
```

This is the part that I added:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/storeadmin/[a-z]{2}/user/login
RewriteRule ^/storeadmin/([a-z]{2}) %{HTTP_HOST}/store/$1/user/login [R=301,L]
```

What is wrong whit it? I tried also without `%{HTTP_HOST}`. 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
# you were missing a '+' here
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

# use %1 to target the stored expressions with () from the RewriteCond
# use $1 to target the stored expressions with () from the RewriteRule
# the ? means that the preceeding character may or may not exist
# NC flag means the RewriteRule to be matched in a case-insensitive manner.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?storeadmin/([a-z]{2})/user/login/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /store/%1/user/login [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: It works, definitely! Can you give me a little clarity? First: What does this question mark do in the end and the beginning of the `RewriteCond`. Second: the [NC] flag and the last : `%1`. The percent means dynamically string ? Thank you again :)

Comment: Thak you very much!